# relationship inside grid field works but throws errors

Tags: relationships, grid, php-errors

I've got a grid field with a text column (amount) and a relationship column (product). The data is outputted perfectly but I'm getting lots of php errors on the page:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 18
Filename: relationship_parser/Tree_builder.php
Line Number: 536

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: libraries/Functions.php
Line Number: 810

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)
Filename: core/Common.php
Line Number: 412
```

my template:

```
{bt-pack-contents}
    <li>{bt-pack-contents:amount} {bt-pack-contents:product:title}</li>
{/bt-pack-contents}
```

this also works:

```
{bt-pack-contents}
    <li>{bt-pack-contents:amount} {bt-pack-contents:product}{bt-pack-contents:product:title}{/bt-pack-contents:product}</li>
{/bt-pack-contents}
```

As soon as I remove the {bt-pack-contents:product:title} tag all errors are gone. Any thoughts on what might be going wrong?

Comment: Workaround: I ended up using Playa and Matrix in stead of native grid and relationship. No more issues.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on an EE 2.7.3. I cannot switch to playa/matrix due to a large amount of existing data.